# Android Sqlite techniques

Tags: android, sqlite, helper

I'm a beginner and i have 2 questions:

1. What's the difference between rawQuery and execSQL?
2. What are the benefits of using the "best practices" sqlite helper and relative functions insert(), update(), delete() and ContentValues and such ? that seem pointless to me (I come from php mysql).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execSQL : 
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data like insert update delete like sql command you write  and it doesn't return value for you like  other method  like update return for you the number of effected  cols.

rawQuery 
Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set and  it's making query only (select only).

second :

using best practice because it will help you in maintain your code and strongly type result and provide more code for you  for you   like i said above using update will return number that you need to check for success operation

hope it useful for you